# Finding intersection between two dataframes iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, intersection

I have the following two dataframes and would like to find their intersection.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"0": [1524, 8788, 9899, 27172],
                   "1": [1333, 4476, 78783, 90832],
                   "2": [2021, 2022, 34522, 38479]})

print(df1)

      0      1      2
0   1524   1333   2021
1   8788   4476   2022
2   9899  78783  34522
3  27172  90832  38479
```

`df2` is a list type with one column '0' which looks like this:

```
          0
[1123, 2021, 1333, 6636], 
[1245, 2022, 4477, 0], 
[1524, 2023, 1, 27172], 
[2021, 2023, 90832, 38479]
```

Expected output should be intersection of df1 and df2, for example:

```
df3 = [2021, 1333],
      [2022],
      [0],
      [90832, 38479]
```

What I read so far relates to finding intersection for a single list, and not two dataframes with different data types. My end goal is to compute **precision** which is the `intersection of df1 and df2 divide by the total number of my recommendations from df1` , which is 3.
**Additional note from comments below:**
The rows are aligned and would be compared pairwise.
`[0]` in df3 does not appear anywhere but could work in case the intersection is 0.

Comment: Are rows aligned between two dataframes? Compare 0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, etc?

Comment: Why is `[0]` in `df3`?  Zero does not appear in `df1`.

Comment: Yes, the rows are aligned. That's correct, I would like to compare row-wise.

Comment: True @hilberts_drinking_problem I added zero there that's if in case the intersection is 0, it surely can be represented by other alternatives

Comment: @SquidGame I think an empty list `[]` would be more logical for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

`df1`:

```
       0      1      2
0   1524   1333   2021
1   8788   4476   2022
2   9899  78783  34522
3  27172  90832  38479
```

and `df2`:

```
                            0
0    [1123, 2021, 1333, 6636]
1       [1245, 2022, 4477, 0]
2      [1524, 2023, 1, 27172]
3  [2021, 2023, 90832, 38479]
```

You can use `set.intersection` inside list comprehension:

```
df1_lst = df1.to_numpy().tolist()
df2_lst = df2.to_numpy().tolist()
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[list(set(i).intersection(j[0]))] for i,j in zip(df1_lst, df2_lst)], columns=['col'])
```

Output:

```
              col
0    [1333, 2021]
1          [2022]
2              []
3  [90832, 38479]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=[[1123, 2021, 1333, 6636], 
[1245, 2022, 4477, 0], 
[1524, 2023, 1, 27172], 
[2021, 2023, 90832, 38479]]

s=[set(x)for x in lst]#put list in set

s1=df1.agg(set,1).to_list()#make list of list of row values

[list(x.intersection(y)) for x, y in zip(s, s1)]
```

out

```
[[1333, 2021], [2022], [], [90832, 38479]]
```